# Asp.net MVC2 with iPad

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have just come across the Mobile application toolkit which enables me to expose my web app built on Asp.NET MVC 2 on an iPhone and other mobile devices. However how would I expose my site on an iPad?

Are there any toolkits out there?

JD

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "expose"?

Comment: An iPad is just 4 iPhones iDuct-taped together. So you're good to go with the Mobile Application Toolkit. http://www.devdaily.com/sites/default/files/users/user3/ipad-ipod-duct-tape.png

Comment: @David: Sorry, I just meant show my web site content or allow access to it using an iphone/ipad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what I do is just using a Framework. I used to use [jQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/) but now I'm using [jQueryMobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) as it works better in Android and Opera Mobile (to use with Nokias or any mobile device) much better that the last time I use jQTouch (before [Jonathan](http://www.jonathanstark.com/) took over the project).

if a user is using an **iPad or any other desktop browser**, I sent the user to my **desktop views**, if using any other **iDevice, Android or Opera Mobile**, I set the user to use jQueryMobile Views.

**It's quite easy to accomplish this with MVC2**, the controllers are the same, methods are the same, you just redirect to a **different view**.

I choose to should my web application in desktop mode in the iPad cause I add some meta to it and that works fantasticaly fine in the iPad, you could also use any Framework or develop a new html5 view to work with the iPad if you don't want to mess up what you have already.

**You need to rememer** that in an iPad, there is no "hover" effect, and a click is a tap, though Mobile Safari does a pretty good job on click events, you could create a new set of views that use this new techniques, as well, the full set of Safari CSS3 and other bonus, such as geolocation, browser database, etc

more under **Apple Technical Note**: [Preparing Your Web Content for iPad](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#technotes/tn2010/tn2262/index.html)

I hope this helps, if you need more, please more precise question

Comment: Thank you so much for the information. I have just downloaded the 
Web Application Toolkit for Mobile Web Applications. Do you have any experience with this? I will look at jQueryMobile. To think only a week ago I just started looking at MVC/JQuery/Css and now there my be work with the iPhone and iPad.

Comment: I would suggest to drop that toolkit, jQueryMobile is fantastic and will work in so many devices - see here in how many and how good http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/ - though they are in alpha 2, I got plenty with it. you can give jQTouh a go as well. check their examples - you will need a good know-how of javascript and CSS if you want more than the default of both frameworks. - Keep in mind, a mobile device web application, is just a normal website with more rules like, sizes, user interface, etc. but it's still a website.

Comment: Thank you you have been so helpful. I just read the toolkit start up which looks very easy. I'll browse over to jQueryMobile and see what that involves. Lots to learn but I am enjoying it and I really appreciate the help from you.